# Issues enabling IIS-ASPNET module in windows nano server

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows, nano-server

I am running an application that requires IIS-ASPNET & IIS-ASPNET45 features enabled. When i run below commands in windowsservercore container it runs fine, but fails in nano server with below error message.

```
PS C:\> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -all

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name IIS-ASPNET45 is unknown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -all
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMExcepti
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Can someone help,

Answer (score 0):

New Windows nanoserver images (1709+) do not feature IIS option anymore. Only older versions do. See comparison of original nanoserver image vs 1709.

Here is details [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/nano-in-semi-annual-channel)

`PS C:\> docker run -it --rm microsoft/nanoserver powershell get-windowsoptionalfeature -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -online
PS C:\> docker run -it --rm microsoft/nanoserver:1709 powershell get-windowsoptionalfeature -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -online
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 19e874a98ea8bdd2175f2f1052adadc0b8ee015178f00441e874189addf729ad encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"powershell get-windowsoptionalfeature -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -online","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[64,213]}.`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gregory, but i am a bit confused. Are you saying that i cant get IIS-ASPNET45 feature enabled ? I am using latest nanoserver version and running get-windowsoptional feature works, but when i try to enable it, throws same error.

Comment: Yes, you can not use that feature  since nanoserver does not support full ASP.NET framework. In addition to that nanoserver version 1709 and above removes IIS as well